# Can't generate QueryDSL's QClass when upgrading to 5.0.0 (com.querydsl.sql.Configuration is not registered)

Tags: maven, querydsl

I upgraded my QueryDSL's version to 5.0.0 ([for the JTS upgrade](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2404)) but now, the plugin throw an error when regenerating QClass using `mvn clean install` : `com.querydsl.sql.Configuration is not registered`.

Here is my configuration :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        <options>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I have same issue

Answer (score 1):

Use the dependency below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're encouraged to use:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <classifier>jpa</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Instead of the `apt-maven-plugin` for Querydsl 4.0.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I quite have the same issue. In order to make it work I specified with the apt-maven-plugin only the folders where my entities were like here :

```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>common.persistence.entity.**</include>
                                <include>security.persistence.entity.**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                    <processors>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </processors>
                </configuration>
```

Don't know if this would help you but. You should giv it a try !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31340260)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend getting rid of the plugin altogether and using the dependency classifier instead:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
```